# How to make matrix using column matrix?

Tags: python

I wanna know how to make a matrix using the column matrix.

For example, I have a `[1,2,3]` column matrix.

I wanna make the matrix

```
[ 1 0 0

  2 1 0 

  3 2 1

  0 3 2

  0 0 3 ]
```

like this.

So How can I make it? Is there some module to make this matrix in python?

Comment: You need to put the code of what you have tried and not ask for the answer straight away

Answer (score 1):

Try using `numpy` and `np.zeros`

```
import numpy as np 

def get_matrix(col):
    mat = np.zeros((len(col) * 2 - 1, len(col)))
    for i in range(len(col)):
        mat[i : i + len(col), i] = col
    return mat

col = [1, 2, 3]
print(get_matrix(col))
```

prints:

```
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [2., 1., 0.],
       [3., 2., 1.],
       [0., 3., 2.],
       [0., 0., 3.]])
```

and

```
col = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(get_matrix(col))
```

prints

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [3., 2., 1., 0., 0.],
       [4., 3., 2., 1., 0.],
       [5., 4., 3., 2., 1.],
       [0., 5., 4., 3., 2.],
       [0., 0., 5., 4., 3.],
       [0., 0., 0., 5., 4.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 5.]])
```

as expected I believe. Otherwise give more precision about how you build your matrix.

Also there may be a smarter (more efficient?) way to do this using pure numpy but I believe this loop is quite readable and not so inefficient

Comment: thank you very much! but How can I use this code when the column matrix is the complex matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to obtain the answer.

```
import numpy as np

a=[1,2,3]
a.extend([0]*2)
d=[np.roll(a,i) for i in range(3)]
print(d)

[array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0]), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3])]
```